# When to apply design-changes from PreferenceActivity in MainActivity? @onResume?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

i`m new to android-coding and am working on my first app. I have the following question:

If one wants the user to be able (for instance) to change the backgroundcolor of the app in PreferenceActivity, where should this change be applied in the MainActivity of the app?

In my case i have many views on a few pages which i want to be customizable in one or the other way. I do it like this:

1. If there are relevant changes in PreferenceActivity i set a flag and save the changes and the flag in SharedPreferences
2. Since onResume of MainActivity is called whenever the user returns, i read from the flag in SharedPreferences if changes of the views need to be made and if so, i apply the changes.

I want to use a flag because i dont want to apply the changes again and again whenever onResume is called because its many views that are affected and i dont want to slow down the app unnecessarily.

How would you all do this? i`ll be happy about any hint. Maybe i should even apply the changes in PReferenceActivity already? i dont know......

thx